# Perform logout in next activity on actionbar

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) tutorial . I have login and logout by facebook in MainActivity , and the problem is how can i perform a logout in the next (Home) activity ? For HomeActivity , i create on my own(by create new activity).
**Here is the code for home activity**

```
package com.innoark.motivator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.Session;

public class Home extends Activity {

    Button button;
    MenuItem logout , writepost , send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            if (menu.size() == 0) {
                writepost = menu.add(R.string.writepost);
                logout = menu.add(R.string.settings);

            }
            return true;
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            logout = null;
            writepost = null;
        }
    return true;
    }

//  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.equals(logout)) {

            return true;
        }
        if (item.equals(writepost)){
            Intent intent = new Intent (this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for Logout you can check it ..............

```
    signoutbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signout_btn);
    signoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            SharedPreferences mSharedPreference =getSharedPreferences("SharedData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mSaveState = mSharedPreference.edit();
            mSaveState.putBoolean("LoginSession", false);
            mSaveState.commit();
            Intent signout = new Intent(HotTaxiTabActivity.this,Login.class);
            signout.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(signout);
        }
    });




 if (item.equals(logout)) 
  {

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreference =getSharedPreferences("SharedData",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mSaveState = mSharedPreference.edit();
            mSaveState.putBoolean("LoginSession", false);
            mSaveState.commit();
            Intent signout = new Intent(HotTaxiTabActivity.this,Login.class);
            signout.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(signout);

    }
     return true;
```

Comment: Thanks , but how can i add the logout function in actionbar ? in above that's onOptionItemSelected for logout .

Comment: It is not working for me. Is that logout code for facebook login ? this is the tutorial i used http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/